# dropdown al abrir se va hacia arriba

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

El problema que tengo es que no puedo hacer que el `div` con filtros que tengo se abra siempre hacia abajo sin importar si se ve todo el contenido, porque cuando el `height` que hay hacia abajo no es suficiente se va hacia arriba. 
Acá dejo el código a ver si alguien me dice alguna propiedad que me pueda ayudar, obviamente falta el contenido del `div` que se despliega que son varios filtros.

**Utilizo bootstrap 4.3**

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-filtrar dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filtrar
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu checkbox-dropdown keep-open-on-click" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido al sitio, te recomiendo leas [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que así podamos ayudarte con tu problema. Tal cual está tu código, no se muestra el error que mencionas, podrías por ejemplo, compartir el CSS de las clases que son tuyas y no propias de Bootstrap, así tal vez eso nos indique algo.

Comment: 1) "...porque cuando el height que hay hacia abajo no es suficiente se va hacia arriba." De esto infiero que tu elemento con la clase `dropdown` está en un contenedor con alto fijo. 2) "...obviamente falta el contenido del div que se despliega que son varios filtros" ¿De cuántos filtros se está hablando? O mejor dicho, ¿con cuántos elementos del menú dropdown se está tratando? 3) Asociado con las dos cosas que acabo de mencionar: Faltan detalles. Tal cual como está tu código ahora, no se puede reproducir al 100%. Concuerdo con @JheymanMejia, pon el código completo para que se pueda ver mejor.

Comment: Tal vez [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242702/force-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-to-always-display-at-the-bottom-and-allow-it-go-of) te ayude, justo preguntan lo mismo que tú en el stack overflow no español

Answer (score 0):

Es como dibuja [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap), busca en `bootstrap.css`

```
.dropup .dropdown-menu,.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      /*top: auto;*/
      /*bottom: 100%;*/
      margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Si comentas el `top` y el `bottom`, lo corrige para esos controles que dibuja hacia arriba